# How to query not available value in the column?

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset

I've a table as follows:

[image]

From this, I'm trying to get the user_id's where status IS NOT **STATUS 4 AVAILABLE** . In other word the results I'm expecting are:

> User Ids: 17, 19 and 20.

I tried many queries but nothing didn't worked for me. For example I tried.

```
SELECT user_id WHERE status NOT IN (4)
```

The above above query still returns as follows:

> User Ids: 1, 17, 18, 19 and 20.

I know the reason why it's returning but I'm not sure how to overcome the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to do a subquery for this.  For example:

```
 Select user_id from table Where user_id not in 
         (select user_id from table where status = 4 and user_id is not null);
```

This allows you to exclude all user_id's that are in a status of 4.

Comment: Note that if `user_id` is a nullable field, you'll want to include `and user_id is not null` in the subquery's WHERE clause.  NOT IN doesn't work well with NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 4 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

or, alternatively:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2
                  WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND status = 4)
```